# Replace IDs in a table with actual values in DAX Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery, daxstudio

I have two tables the first one contains a value and label combination. The second table contains a column containing IDs(matching with table 1 ) in cell separated by commas

Output : replace all IDs with respective values with commas intact

[image]

sample output

[image]

Comment: Can you share a .pbix?

Comment: That will be difficult, the two tables are different sources, no common columns

Comment: You need to share some sample data in [table](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/302471/how-to-put-tables-in-stack-overflow) with clearly laid-out logic to reach the desired output based on the sample data, if you really want a quick answer in this forum.